# Dynamic Sum query

Tags: excel, vba, sum, finance

I have 2 Columns as follows

```
A        B           
Trade    0
         0
         1
         7
         6
```

Now once ColA returns "Trade" - I want to return in ColC - the first value that is greater than 0, in this instance it will be the value 1, located in cell B4. Therefore I want it to sum until >0 and return that figure.

From comments:

> I was thinking along the lines of
>
> =if(B2>0,B2,B3)
>
> ... however I need to extend this to say if B3 is not >0 give me B4? But it just seems long winded and not sustainable for 10000+ lines of data

Comment: I have tried various IF and SUM if functions but none of them will get me to what I want. Any ideas? :)

Comment: If you have *'tried various IF and SUM if functions'* then show one or more of the attempts (working or not).

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of =if(B2>0,B2,B3) however I need to extend this to say if B3 is not >0 give me B4? But it just seems long winded and not sustainable for 10000+ lines of data

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot determine how your sample formula addresses *'once ColA returns "Trade"'*. For all intents and purposes, your sample data has *Trade* in A1. You've described the scope of the data as being in the 10K rows areas. How many *Trade* values are there in column A? Are the values in column B always in ascending order? Do they restart when a new category in column A is arrived at?

Answer (score 0):

> Caveat: I cannot think of any non-array formula that would accomplish this and 10,000 lines of any data is going to be hard on the calculation load with an array formula.

I will be basing this formula-based solution on the following sample data which is the best that I can determine from your original question.

[image: SUM staggered data with conditions]

With a list of the text strings from column A in D2:D5, I've used the following *array formula* in E2.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2,A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B )), MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(B:B, MATCH(D2,A:A, 0)):INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,B:B ))>0, 0))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered correctly, they can be filled down as necessary. Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: SUM staggered data with conditions INDEX formula]

This formula does dynamically truncate the column references but I have not tried it on 10K rows of data. Expect some calculation lag.